# Unity- Colliding Passing Through

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made airplane shooter in Unity. First I make player and I already make all the code. And it works well. And then now I want to change the player object. I had already put the script and give same name and tag as the used player that I make. And the colliding is a mess. I can shoot enemies down. But the enemies can't shoot or hit me. The enemies bullet and the enemies passing through my player object.
I don't know why. Please help me to find the problem. Just tell me the possibilities of this problem cause.
Here is the screenshot of my new object component

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are way, way too many possibilities that could be the cause. You can't just give us a nominal description and ask us to list everything that comes to mind. Please supply the code used for collision handling, and an idea of what components are on the player/enemy and any projectiles you may be creating. Are there Rigidbodies on your objects? Are some collisions disabled in the collision matrix? Are any colliders marked as Trigger? Are you using physics to move your objects, or just `Translate()`? The list goes on, and on, and on, because there isn't enough information in this question.

Comment: because i'm sure there's no a mistake with the code. Because everything works well before i change my player object. Yes i had already put the rigid body and u didn't marked it as trigger. I'm using code to make it move

Comment: For the poor description that you provide, and going to the essential problem of changing an object for another identical, maybe you had your player object set in the Inspector for some script, and now, because you changed the object, isn't linked anymore

Comment: @NickyApriliani Interesting exception at the bottom - GameObject has undefined tag? That could be pretty relevant, if tags play a part in your collision handling.

Comment: No i didn't set it in another inspector, I only use tags to call the player in code @cjf93

Comment: It will go to the code, and point in the tag "Boundary" and "Enemies".
Though i had already use that tag in my object. I don't know why @Serlite

Comment: My first object is prefab, and new object is a model. will it make problems? @Serlite

Comment: @NickyApriliani It shouldn't create any issues - I'd just make sure any references you previously in your scripts had are still correct. When the enemies shoot at the player, are they creating projectile objects, or raycasting?

Comment: Check your layers and which layers can collide with others. One mistake I used to make often was setting the player bullets and enemy bullets on the same layer. I use layers to make sure the player can't run into their own bullets but if you make the mistake I used to then you might also be ignoring the enemies. To help with debugging I would suggest adding functions for OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionExit, OnTriggerEnter, and OnTriggerExit and debugging something to the console or hitting a break point. If nothing is firing then the collisions are ignored by the engine and not your code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Collider has the "Is Trigger" checked, that may be causing the error.

[image]